Global variable evaluation when used in function
I'm trying to figure out why a variable defined in global scope is not fully evaluated, when it's used in function. This is not about use of local variables, rather it's about evaluation of the global variables.
Here's an example (I ran it in wxMaxima):
f(x) := g^2 + x*b $
g : 6*a $

f(1), a: 2, b:3, numer;

   36*a^2+3

As could be seen, a ends up not evaluated in the f(1) result. I expected f(1) to evaluate to 147.
In this simple case "full" evaluation can be obtained by adding eval to the environment:
f(1), a: 2, b:3, eval, numer;

    147

However, in more complex cases (involving functions and sums) this "additional" evaluation does not seem to be enough, at times it requires usage of ev(..., eval), eval, numer; constructs. I'm not sure if this is how it's supposed to be.
Of course, it could be possible to add a as function argument f(x,a), but in the context the function definition logically is f(x); a is more like a configuration parameter, so indeed it is global.

Maxima implements a "one time" evaluation policy. When a variable is evaluated, whatever value it has is retrieved and substituted into the result, and whether that value itself has some other value is ignored (barring modifications imposed by global flags or functions with nonstandard evaluation). That policy was adopted to make it easier to predict what would happen when evaluating any particular expression. I'll try to respond to your specific question at some point.
